# Action Generics from Base Type

Tags: c#, generics

I would like an `IEnumerable<Action<T>> subscriptions` which is an array of actions, each with a different type parameter - I would like to pass a list in to a service constructor to loop through these and register but the compiler complains (not surprisingly).

Is there any way to achieve the ability to pass in a base type which has a derived specific implementation, and loop through the list?

```
class InternalBusService
{
    private InternalBus bus;

    public InternalBusService(IEnumerable<Action<T>> subscriptions)
    {
        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            this.bus.Subscribe<T>(subscription);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to need some more info on `InternalBus`.  Can you show us the `Subscribe` method?

Comment: InternalBusService constructor will need to be InstructorBusService<T> to leverage T within itself.

Comment: What are you subscribing? When the *subscribed* (as you named it) delegate invokes, it happens nothing to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand that you want to pass in `IEnumerable<Action<T>>` where T for each action in the enumerable is NOT the same type, that isn't possible the way you are doing it.

Perhaps you could do something like this "concept code" below (meaning its just to show you what I'm thinking, it isn't necessarily a solution).

```
public interface IActionWrapper
{

    bool AcceptsParameterType(Type t);
    void PerformAction(object o);
}

public class ActionWrapper<T> : IActionWrapper
{
    Action<T> yourAction {get;set;}

    public bool AcceptsParameterType(Type t)
{
return t is T;
}

public void PerformAction(object o)
{
  yourAction((T)o);
}

}
```

Then you could pass `IEnumerable<IActionWrapper>>` into your function which isn't generic-typed and would support multiple types by its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
class InternalBusService<T>
    where T : SomeType
{
    public InternalBusService(IEnumerable<Action<T>> subscriptions)
    {
        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            this.bus.Subscribe<T>(subscription);
        }
    }
}
```

`where T : SomeType` can be any type that you want to restrict `T` to.

Comment: Hi, seems this answer does not as what OP says.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you mean. Have a look here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To solve compiler error:

```
class InternalBusService<T>
{
    public InternalBusService(IEnumerable<Action<T>> subscriptions) { }
}
```

But not sure that it's what you're trying to achieve actually.